# mount "nolocks" option ignored on Mavericks 10.9.1?

Tags: macos, mount

I'm not 100% sure if this is just my misinterpretation of the mount output, or if this is actually an issue.  I'm mounting an nfs share with the following command:

```
mount -t nfs -o nolocks,noowners 10.0.0.1:/vol/shared ~/shared
```

But when I look at the output of `mount` I see the following:

```
10.0.0.1:/vol/shared on /Users/ryan/shared (nfs, nodev, nosuid, noowners, mounted by ryan)
```

Why isn't nolocks listed in the options?  The reason I need this option enabled is that the server I'm connecting to doesn't have locking enabled, and when I try and use the share I experience extremely slow performance as a result (at least this is the most likely reason).  I'm fairly sure that it isn't mounting the share with locking disabled, because I'm still experiencing the same issue.

Comment: What is the output of `mount_nfs`?

Comment: usage: mount_nfs [-o options] server:/path directory

Comment: No, I meant if you mount using `mount_nfs` rather than `mount`.

Comment: Ah. The result is the same.

Answer (score -2):

```
nfsstat -m
```

It shows the options from mount_nfs

Comment: I don't see how this answers the OP's question. Can you expand on the details, please?

Comment: To see if the option nolocks is applied you have to look at the output of the command 'nfsstat -m' not 'mount'

Comment: The OP didn't ask to *see* what the options were, the question was *why was the option being ignored?*

Comment: You have to start by looking in the right place first to see if the option is being ignored, from the output of mount you can't tell

Comment: Here is an output example
# mount
example.com:/export/home on /home (nfs, nodev, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
# nfsstat -m
NFS parameters: vers=3,tcp,port=2049,nomntudp,hard,nointr,noresvport,negnamecache,callumnt,nolocks,quota,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,readahead=16,dsize=4096,nordirplus,nodumbtimr,timeo=10,maxgroups=16,acregmin=5,acregmax=60,acdirmin=5,acdirmax=60,nomutejukebox,nonfc,sec=sys

Comment: Perhaps you should put that explanation in your answer.  As you are new, it might be a good idea to review the post [How to Write a Good Answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) found in our [Help Center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help)